# Is it possible to force the AR object ids to start from a certain value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, rails-activerecord

Is there a way to set the ID's for some AR model to start from a specific value? ( Say 1000 )? I need this only for my rspec tests, not for code that will run in production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For mysql you can do it like this

`ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;`

And for postgresql you can do it like this

`ALTER SEQUENCE tablename_id_seq RESTART 1000;`

Answer (score 0):

primary keys are managed by your db, no way to change that directly in AR.
see benchwarmer's reply for doing it via your db.

For rspec tests you can just stub `Model#id` and `Model.find` etc.